# A simple integration question on the Dirac and Heaviside 'functions'

Tags: integration, derivatives, distribution-theory

I am trying to find the indefinite integral wrt $x$ of $\delta(ct-x)$;
so I let $u=ct-x$, then $du/dx=-1$ and $dx=-du$
 so the integral becomes

$$-\int \delta(u)du = -\theta(u) = -\theta(ct-x) $$

but Wolfram Alpha Pro gives $\theta(x-ct)$ as the result. Note the variables are swapped.

Here $\theta$ is the Heaviside step, $\delta$ is the Dirac delta distribution, $x$ and $t$ are variables, and $c$ is a constant $>0$.

I checked my answer as follows

$$d/dx (-1)\theta(ct-x)=-\delta(ct-x)(-1)=\delta(ct-x)  $$

so it checks out (I think).

Checking Wolfram's answer gives

$$d/dx (\theta(x-ct))=\delta(x-ct)= \delta(ct-x) $$

so it also checks out.

MY QUESTION IS: *who is right, Wolfram Alpha or me? Or both and am I missing an identity?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two answers differ by a constant which is why the derivatives are the same. Note that $\theta(x) = -\theta(-x)+1$. So the two expressions you and wolfram got are not equal, they differ by 1, but since you are taking an indefinite integral the difference is in the $+C$.

Comment: So who is right?

Comment: You both are, Indefinite integrals are only knowable to an additive constant and that is what the answers differ by. Both answers are correct as you found by confirming that their derivatives are equal. I would put a $+C$ in your answer but that's a technicality.

Comment: In your identity $\theta(x) = -\theta(-x)+1$, can x be replaced by $f(y)$?  That is, can $x$ be an expression?

Comment: Yes, my x is not your x it is just a place holder $\theta(a) = -\theta(-a)+1 \forall a$. To see this plot $\theta(x)$ and $-\theta(-x)$.

Comment: Great answer-thanks.  See my other question  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3420660/147776